# How to get all items in from of Text from Ordered collection

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

simple question i got

```
|list string|
list:= #('ab' 'efghij' 'lmnopqrst'). "Ordered collection"
list do:[:each| "string with:each"  i know this is not right how do i add items ].
```

I tried streams too it returned me this "an ordered collection('ab' 'efghij' 'lmnopqrst')"

All i need is a single Text that has

```
'abc efghij lmnopqrst '
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Pharo you can do

```
Character space join: list
```

If join: is not available and it should perform well then you can use a stream variant

```
String streamContents: [:stream| 
    list 
        do [:each| stream nextPutAll: each ]
        separatedBy: [ stream nextPut: Character space ]
```

Answer (score 3):

`Object` class has defined a `#asString` message that reads:

```
"Answer a string that represents the receiver."
```

So, you can do:

```
| aList aStringsList |
aList := #('ab' 'efghij' 'lmnopqrst'). "Array"
aStringsList := aList collect: [ :each | each asString ]
```

And `aStringsList` will be an `Array` of the `String`s returned by the invocation of `#asString` in each of `aList`'s members.

If you want to concatenate all of them in a single `String`, you can use the `#inject:into:` method of the collections instead of `#collect:`:

```
aList inject: '' into: [ :text :each | text , each asString , ' ' ]
```

If you print that you'll get the `'ab efghij lmnopqrst '` you want :)

Comment: Nice explanation, but you are using a [schlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm) which is highly inefficient if the list grows. Rather chose the solution form Norbert using #join: or #streamContents:.